# Bulk Delete Repeating Events

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

Created an Event, and had it repeating twice a week. As a result it created about 100 Events, all occurrences of that event happening twice a week for the entire year.

How do I bulk delete these repeating events? Changing the Repeating frequency doesn't delete already created events. I can see that I can remove each event one at a time, but that's a lot.

Hopefully someone can help solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably the 'new' way to do this would be using SearchKit and FormBuilder - i believe the Action to 'delete event' exists (though it is possible we created it using another extension)

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **events >>> event templates,** find the template you used to create the child items. In the templates-table, you see a href showing the number of child items linked to the parent event. Or just open the parent event and click on the **tab "manage linked events"**.

There you have the possibility to **select them all/multiple child items and chose "delete events" from the actions dropdown-menu above.**

[image]